# I want to add the below chatbot html code to index(main) file of WordPress sites how can I do that

Tags: plugins, html

It work's locally on my system but how can I make it work in WordPress. It doesn't even show up in WordPress might be because of overlapping

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style>
        @keyframes slideInRight {
          from {
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            visibility: visible;
          }
        
          to {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          }
        }
        
        button.chatLauncher {
          animation-duration: 0.5s;
          transition-duration: 0.5s;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 32px;
          right: 32px;
          z-index: 9999;
          border: 4px solid #981f25;
          padding: 1em;
          border-radius: 8px;
          margin: 0;
          text-decoration: none;
          background-color: #ffffff;
          color: #454545;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 1rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          text-align: left;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          -moz-appearance: none;
          width: 264px;
          opacity: 0;
        }
    
        button.chatLauncher.open {
          animation-name: slideInRight;
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        button.chatLauncher:hover,
        button.chatLauncher:focus {
          background-color: rgb(225, 225, 254);
          border: 4px solid #0053ba;
        }
        
        button.chatLauncher:focus {
          outline: 1px solid #0053ba;
          outline-offset: -4px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- We want to hide this element initially, because web chat isn't ready yet. -->
    <button type="button" class="chatLauncher" style="display:none;">
      <div>
        Metal Roof Virtual Assistant.
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Powered By NextGen</strong>
      </div>
    </button>
    <script>
      window.watsonAssistantChatOptions = {
        integrationID: "5689411d-538c-44c2-87c5-f7dd2bc156be", // The ID of this integration.
          region: "us-south", // The region your integration is hosted in.
          serviceInstanceID: "f6c21fcb-341c-4546-aa96-1587230b3fec", // The ID of your service instance.
    
        showLauncher: false,
        onLoad: function(instance) {
          // Select the button element from the page.
          const button = document.querySelector('.chatLauncher');
      
          // Add the event listener to open your web chat.
          button.addEventListener('click', function clickListener() {
            instance.openWindow();
          });
      
          // Render the web chat. Nothing appears on the page, because the launcher is
          // hidden and the web chat window is closed by default.
          instance.render().then(function() {
            // Now that web chat has been rendered (but is still closed), we make the
            // custom launcher button visible.
            button.style.display = 'block';
            button.classList.add('open');
          });
        }
      };
    
      setTimeout(function(){const t=document.createElement('script');t.src="https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.appdomain.cloud/versions/" + (window.watsonAssistantChatOptions.clientVersion || 'latest') + "/WatsonAssistantChatEntry.js";document.head.appendChild(t);});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with copy pasting it in the index.php file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add only button HTML code and script code into the footer.php file and check, please make sure into the front end your button is loaded you might also need to do some CSS on that button for proper placements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).